# How to put a .txt file into a DataSource?

Tags: c#, text, datagridview, datasource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting a .txt file into a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095359/putting-a-txt-file-into-a-datagridview)

When I click an open button I would like to choose a file and place it into a `DataSource` to futher be worked into a `DataGridView`.

Right now what I have looks like this:

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();

openFile.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
openFile.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt";
openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

try
{
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && openFile.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        // Right now I am loading the file into a RichTextBox
        openFileRTB.LoadFile(openFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        // What I would like to do is load it into a DataSource and then into a DataGridView.
        // So really I would like to remove the openFileRTB line of code and replace it.
        // That is where I need help :).
    }
}

catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path to open.", "Path Not Found Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Here is an example of a file I would be opening (space delimited):

```
Title1 Title2 Title3 Title4 Title5 Title6
abc123 abc123-123-123 225.123 123.456 180 thing99
c123 somethingHERE 987.123 123.456 360 anotherThing1
abc124 somethingHERE225.123 123.456 0 thing99
```

I am very unfamiliar with `DataSource` and `DataGridView` so if I could get some help with how it works and what needs to happen, how it would look, etc. that would be greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks.

Comment: _"into a DataSource"_? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @Stakx: Well I would like to use an IBindingSource so I can populate the DataGridView from a txt file

Comment: @theNoobGuy, `IBindingSource` is not a container. You cannot put anything "into" it. Instead, it has its own `DataSource` property that must be set (meaning: your data must go somewhere else, e.g. into a `DataTable` -- see the linked question). So an `IBindingSource` is not a data source, but more akin to an adapter, or decorator, for another data source.

Comment: @Stakx: Thanks for some clarification. Hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the lines and loop all rows/columns to generate the DataTable:

For example(VB.NET):

```
Dim separator = " "c
Dim fileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
Dim tbl As New DataTable(fileName)
Dim query = From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
            Let row = line.Split(separator)

If query.Any Then
   For Each col In query(0).row
         'build DataColumns from first line'
         tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col))
   Next
   If query.Count > 1 Then
       For rowIndex = 1 To query.Count - 1
           Dim newRow = tbl.NewRow
           For colIndex = 0 To query(rowIndex).row.Length - 1
               Dim colValue = query(rowIndex).row(colIndex)
               newRow(colIndex) = colValue
           Next
           tbl.Rows.Add(newRow)
       Next
   End If
End If
```

This works just as well without LINQ (now also in C# ;)):

```
....
var rows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
if (rows.Length != 0) {
    foreach (string headerCol in rows(0).Split(separator)) {
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerCol));
    }
    if (rows.Length > 1) {
        for (rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++) {
            var newRow = tbl.NewRow();
            var cols = rows(rowIndex).Split(separator);
            for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols.Length; colIndex++) {
                newRow(colIndex) = cols(colIndex);
            }
            tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a little bit.. not very familiar with VB.net though haha

Comment: @theNoobGuy: i've recently edited my answer and provided a C# example.

Comment: `round(-0.49)` for answering a duplicate question. ;)

Comment: @stakx: oh, i have just seen that the other question is not only similar/duplicate but also from the same OP. Thanks for clarifying, i've added my answer there so that this can be closed.