# C# DataGridView defined table data that receives data from file

Tags: c#, datagridview, openfiledialog

I'm really new to coding so I'm struggling to get an answer for my question directly.
I tried to find answer for my question on many ways (YouTube, stack overflow, google) but couldn't get my program to run correctly.

What I need my program to do is get a value from an m3u file into the appropriate cell on my data table and not read and add absolutely everything.

What I have found online is mainly how to read text/csv/excel and import all the data from the file itself, this is not what I really need or code that i do not understand how to implement for my use, like that question: [Reading from .txt file, then exporting data to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498614/reading-from-txt-file-then-exporting-data-to-datagridview).

I have defined cells that should "suck" the data from the m3u file.

The file m3u file structure is:

> #EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="==== Example1 ====" tvg-logo="" group-title="",==== Example1 ====
>   thestreamingsource1.com
>   #EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="==== Example2 ====" tvg-logo="" group-title="",==== Example2 ====
>   thestreamingsource2.com
>   #EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="==== Example3 ====" tvg-logo="" group-title="",==== Example3 ====
>   thestreamingsource3.com
>   #EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="==== Example4 ====" tvg-logo="" group-title="",==== Example4 ====
>   thestreamingsource4.com

And I need the program to only get the following from the value structure:
tvg-ID (It's okay if it's empty).
tvg-name.
tvg-logo (It's okay if it's empty).
group-title.

So far i have the string that reads all the content of the file and the data grid ready to accept data.

The code behind the form is:

```
public class ThisClass
{
    DataGridView my_datagridview = new DataGridView();
    DataTable my_datatable = new DataTable();

    // Constructor and other methods are in this class,
    // but not showed here...

    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some codes are hidden here...

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;               
            string[] alltext = File.ReadAllLines(sFileName);
            foreach (string text_line in alltext)
            {
               // MessageBox.Show(text_line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the form looks like that:
[image: Read M3u UI]

I'm sorry If the question is already answered but i couldn't find a solution.

Glad if you could help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example and rephrase your question with that. And please provide all information directly in the question (no links should be needed to be clicked for answering the question).

Comment: Thanks ill work on it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting a .txt file into a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095359/putting-a-txt-file-into-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DataGridView_45378237
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataGridView my_datagridview = new DataGridView();//the DataGridView which will be put on the form
        BindingList<MyDatagridviewEntry> myDataGridviewSource = new BindingList<MyDatagridviewEntry>();//the BindingList from which the DataGridView will pull its data


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDataGridView();//set the initial settings of the DataGridView
        }

        private void InitializeDataGridView()
        {
            my_datagridview.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 15, this.Location.Y + 15);//define where to place it in the form(you could obviously just place one directly where you want using the wysiwyg)
            this.Controls.Add(my_datagridview);

            my_datagridview.AutoSize = true;
            my_datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            my_datagridview.DataSource = myDataGridviewSource;//link the DataGridView with the BindingSource

        }

        private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";

            openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "m3u";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|m3u files (*.m3u)|*.m3u";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string sFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                FillDataGridFromFile(sFileName);//send the file to get parsed
            }
        }

        private void FillDataGridFromFile(string incomingFilePath)
        {
            //empty the list
            myDataGridviewSource.Clear();//you may or may not want this... I don't know your full requirements...

            //fill the list
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(incomingFilePath))
            {
                string currentLine = string.Empty;

                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    /*This is not how I would write the production code,
                     * but for the sake of this example, this format works well
                     so that you know what is being done and why.*/
                    string[] splittedString = currentLine.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    string f1 = splittedString.Length > 0 ? splittedString[0] : string.Empty;//if splittedString has more than 0 entries, the use entry[0], else use string.empty
                    string f2 = splittedString.Length > 1 ? splittedString[1] : string.Empty;//if splittedString has more than 1 entries, the use entry[1], else use string.empty
                    string f3 = GetTVGNameFromString(splittedString[0]);//Extract the text from within the string
                    string f4 = splittedString.Length > 3 ? splittedString[3] : string.Empty;//if splittedString has more than 3 entries, the use entry[3], else use string.empty
                    /**/

                    //add the entry to the BindingSource
                    myDataGridviewSource.Add(new MyDatagridviewEntry { Col1 = f1, Col2 = f2, Col3 = f3, Col4 = f4 });
                }
            }
        }



        private string GetTVGNameFromString(string incomingString)
        {
            string retval = string.Empty;
            Regex rgx = new Regex("tvg-name=\"([^\"]*)\"");//use a grouping regex to find what you are looking for
            if (rgx.IsMatch(incomingString))
            {
                return rgx.Matches(incomingString)[0].Groups[1].Value;
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }



    public class MyDatagridviewEntry
    {
        public string Col1 { get; set; }
        public string Col2 { get; set; }
        public string Col3 { get; set; }
        public string Col4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```